# How to load second view in Preference window cocoa

Tags: cocoa, view, preferences

I am developing a cocoa application for mac. I have created a preference window with four buttons in toolbar. I am loading views on click event of buttons. Its working fine.
What I want to know is how to load another view on click of button in a view. Like in preference window of Safari, there is tab named with Privacy. And there is a button 'Details...' in Privacy tab. When we click on that button it shows a new view which shows a list of cookies.
Any Idea how to load view like view loaded on click of 'Details...' button???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several approaches, depending on what you're trying to accomplish. The easiest is probably to create the view you want, but make it hidden when you don't want it to be visible. Then when the user presses the "Details…" button, make it visible (and possibly expand the window if necessary) by calling [-NSView setHidden:NO].

Another way is to make the view a separate view in your .nib file, and when the "Details…" button is pressed, insert the view into the appropriate window using [-NSView addSubView:].

You could also create the view at runtime when the user presses the "Details…" button. That seems like a lot of work, though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried first two approaches. By using these methods I can show views but not as shown in preferences of Safari on click of "Details..." button as discussed in my question. I'm unable to animate it and also toolbar and previous view are not disabled as in Safari. I have created separate views in same .nib file and want to show then by animating as in Safari. Actually I'm new to cocoa development so can you provide me example code for this??

Comment: Waiting for your reply. Can you provide any link or source code for this??

Comment: Sorry, I was away on vacation for a few weeks. It sounds like what you want is a sheet with your additional information in it. [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Sheets.html) are some docs on getting started with sheets.

Comment: Great! If this answers your question, please check the green checkbox next to the big number by my answer. Thanks!